# How can I style my ionic2 app from scratch; prevent any ionic scss from loading?

Tags: sass, ionic2

Building a custom app and I need to not inherit any scss from ionic.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to use Ionic than? You can do pure cordova right ?

Comment: @DenkoMancheski Ionic provides: a set of front-end components (HTML/CSS/JavaScript and AngularJS). I want the other 3 components just not their CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Add this to your package.json file:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_sass": "/src/config/sass.config.js"
}
```

Add the file referenced above to your project with the following js:

```
module.exports = {

    outputFilename: process.env.IONIC_OUTPUT_CSS_FILE_NAME,

    sourceMap: false,

    outputStyle: 'expanded',

    autoprefixer: {
        browsers: [],
        cascade: false
    },
    includePaths: [],

    includeFiles: [
        /app\.scss$/i
    ],

    excludeFiles: [],

    variableSassFiles: [],

    directoryMaps: {},

    excludeModules: [
        '@angular',
        '@ionic',
        '@ionic-native',
        'commonjs-proxy',
        'core-js',
        'ionic-native',
        'rxjs',
        'zone.js'
    ]

};
```

This prevents any sass loading except for any app.scss files.

You can include any needed sass into that file.